# Group by clause in FQL

Tags: facebook

I am trying to use group by clause in my query as,

```
select actor_id
from stream
where source_id = me()
group by actor_id limit 15.
```

But I am getting parser error at the group by. How should we use group by in FQL? Is there any work around for it?

Answer (score 4):

Where is no `GROUP BY` clause support in `FQL`:

> FQL can handle simple math, basic boolean operators, AND or NOT logical operators, and ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses.

You'll need to iterate over results manually to do grouping.

Answer (score -1):

Try Using this method..

```
  def group_by(h, col_name)
    vals = h.map {|hash| hash[col_name]}.uniq
    vals.collect {|val| h.map {|ha| ha  if (ha[col_name] == val)}.compact}.uniq
  end
```

Comment: He asked about Facebook FQL